# Как сортировать массив сначала по цифрам, потом по буквам?

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Имеется JS-массив, который содержит цифры и буквы. Распишем его как `1,A,V,2,3,C`, где `,` это наш условный разделитель. Как сортировать массив так, чтобы получилось на выходе `1, 2, 3, A, C, V`?

Comment: Извините, а разве дефолтная сортировка не сделает ровно это самое? Ведь в "алфавите" ASCII цифры идур раньше, чем буквы

Comment: @S.H. выполнил вот так: `letters.sort(function( a, b ) {return a - b});`, у меня почему-то вразброс сначала цифры, потом буквы, потом опять цифры. Хотя первая часть цифр идет по порядку

Comment: Попробуйте просто letters.sort(), без коллбэка

Answer (score 1):

```
[1, 'A', 'V', 2, 3, 'C'].sort()

// [1, 2, 3, "A", "C", "V"]
```

Comment: `[1, 'A', 'V', 2, 3, 'C', 11].sort()` → `[1, 11, 2, 3, "A", "C", "V"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a.charCodeAt(0) - b.charCodeAt(0))
```